# How to get decimal values with zero on adiition of double type in c#

Tags: c#

Here below is the operations..

```
double d=4.0;
double dd=4.0;
double results=d+dd;
```

it gives at the time of execution

```
results => 8
```

Instead of

```
results => 8.0
```

I would like to get output like below

```
results => 8.0
```

Will anybody tell me how to get decimal value with zero's also

Comment: It depends on how you print the result (printing means transforming the double to a string)

Comment: You need to format the output yourself - the variable "result" is a double & can be printed with decimal point & as many zeroes as you want. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You might want to check at `String.Format()` [examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use String format for desired output. like

```
    String.Format(((Math.Round(results) == results) ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}"), results);
```